# Do I need a delegate to read while using a background worker?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listbox, backgroundworker

I am using a background worker for an app that reads through thousands of files and searches for certain text.  It's basically to find out what accounts are part of account groups, so I'm searching the entire group directory via a loop in a background worker.

I have delegate subs setup to update label text and to add items to listboxes, and it seems to have cleared up any issues I had about illegal threading.  However, I'm not finding specific details about reading through listboxes, for example.  So for instance, if I find the account inside of a group but that group has already been added to my listbox, I don't want to add it again or else it will be a duplicate.

My program is working fine - but from what I've read threading doesn't always throw an error right away.  I'm trying to avoid rolling my app out and having the error come up sporadically.  So my question is: do I need a delegate to READ a listbox too?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it reads like you are using a listbox to store data. You should not do that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : Could be good to explain _why_ he shouldn't. If the user should be able to see/interact with the data, _AND_ that data only exists for the time being, I see no problem with it.

Comment: I forgot to upvote your question earlier. I wanted to make sure I was the first to answer. :)

Comment: Further to my earlier comment, the principle is known as [separation of concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/98734/1115360). Basically, a variable is for the program to use the data and a listbox is for the *user* to interact with the data. As such, the latter may be sadly lacking in performance speed-wise if you want to use it as a data store because it has other things to do too - you have gone to the trouble of using a background thread to *improve* performance so let the UI elements do their thing and the program do its thing.

Comment: That makes sense, @AndrewMorton.  It would probably be a good habit for me to get used to using arrays for data storage/manipulation and only use UI controls to display that information.  Thanks to both of you for your input, guidance, and clarification.  Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I had a few minutes to think about this and have one last question regarding what you said @AndrewMorton.  If I were to switch from using a listbox to using an array, I can always load the data into listboxes after the BGWorker is completed.  So my question is: by using a global/module level array, does that bypass the whole issue of threading in regards to the UI altogether?  To phrase it another way, the concurrency issue described by Visual Vincent seems to be only in regards to accessing UI controls -- an array, as you suggest, would not have this concurrency issue.  Is this correct?

Comment: @AlexS. Correct. For a long-running background process, it might be nice to go to the trouble of updating the listbox every now and then *if* that is of any value to the user.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Great!  Thanks again for your help!  Wonderful advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just as a little terminology note:** Delegates are merely pointers to other methods and do not provide any thread-safety at all themselves. What you are doing is called *invoking methods on the UI thread* (or just *invoking*, for short).

**To answer your question:** The best practice is to ***always*** invoke when accessing UI elements from a background thread. UI elements (controls) should never be accessed from a background thread because the User Interface cannot handle cross-thread calls, since there's a great chance of concurrency (that is, when two threads try to access the same control at the same time).

When the .NET runtime detects a call to a control from another thread than the control was created on it throws an `InvalidOperationException`. It does this in order to prevent you from doing something that could potentially break the application. This detection works rather good, ***but it's not perfect***.

In some cases the runtime doesn't detect that you're performing an illegal cross-thread call, in which case it will not throw an exception. Your application still works, but that doesn't exclude the fact that there can still be concurrency issues.

For instance, if you were to add or remove items from the `ListBox` from the UI thread, while at the same time running a heavy loop over the list box items from the background thread then that would cause your application to break and the loop will most likely throw an exception.

**To summarize:** You can access some control properties without the .NET runtime throwing an `InvalidOperationException`, but if the property is something that affects the control's behaviour/look/contents then the best practice is to always invoke to avoid any concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this.  It sounds like I should setup some functions and return Booleans regarding whether the item is already in the listbox or not. 

Regarding storing data in a listbox, the application I am working on doesn't really have a use to store data longterm.  I'm guessing that instead of storing it in a listbox, Andrew Morton is implying I should be storing data in an array?  If there is no problem storing it in a listbox, then I would prefer to do it that way.  The user may print the results, but often not.  It's not data that would need to be stored long term.

Comment: @AlexS. : That's one possibility, but remember that those functions must invoke/be invoked as well. `Control.Invoke()` is able to return values.

Comment: @AlexS. : Yes, I think that was what he meant; an array or a list type. Storing the values in a list box just for the time being is fine, however if you were to also save/load those to/from a file then you would use some kind of back-end solution.

Comment: @AlexS. : No problem! Glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!